# Blank value when passing values between class on kivy?

Tags: python, oop, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm going to pass values between class or Screen in this case, but the values is empty when I print it. Here's my py code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


class MyLayout(Screen):
    pstd=ObjectProperty(None)
    def save():
        pass

    def calculate(self):
        pstd=self.pstd.text
        pres=self.pres.text
        tres=self.tres.text
        tsep=self.tsep.text
        psep=self.psep.text
        api=self.api.text
        dg=self.sg.text
        pb=self.pb.text
        co2=self.co2.text
        h2s=self.h2s.text
        n2=self.n2.text
        tds=self.tds.text
        if(self.sat.state == "down"):
            cond = 2
        else :
            cond = 1
        print(pstd)
        return pstd
        

    
class MyLayout2(Screen):
    def press(self):
        print(App.get_running_app().my_layout.calculate())
        


    
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
kv = Builder.load_file("tubes.kv")

class TubesApp(App):
    my_layout = MyLayout()
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TubesApp().run()
```

And it's my kv code :

```
WindowManager:
    MyLayout:
    MyLayout2:

<MyLayout>:
    name: "main"
    free:free
    sat:sat
    pstd:pstd
    tres:tres
    pres:pres
    tsep:tsep
    psep:psep
    api:api
    sg:sg
    pb:pb
    co2:co2
    h2s:h2s
    n2:n2
    tds:tds
    btn:btn
    background_color : 71/255,213/255,223/255,1
    canvas.before:
        Color :
            rgba : self.background_color
        Rectangle :
            size : self.size
            pos : self.pos
    FloatLayout :
        size : root.width,root.height
        Label :
            text : "PVT Calculator"
            font_size : 20
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 400,100
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint : {"center_x":0.5,"top" : 1}
            background_color : (35/255,135/255,142/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        Label :
            text : "Oil Data"
            font_size : 20
            size_hint : (0.5,0.09)
            color: 0.3,0.4,0.5,1
            pos_hint : {"center_x":0.25,"top" : 0.8}
            background_color : (71/255,220/255,141/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos

        Label :
            text : "API"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint : {"x":0, "top":0.712}
            background_color : (5/255,95/255,53/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput :
            id:api
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0.25, "top":0.712}

        Label :
            text : "Saturation pressure"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint : {"x":0, "top":0.672}
            background_color : (6/255,124/255,69/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput :
            id:pb
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0.25, "top":0.672}

        Label :
            text : "Spesific Gravity"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0, "top":0.632}
            color: 1,1,1,1
            background_color : (8/255,152/255,85/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput : 
            id:sg
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0.25, "top":0.632}

        Label : 
            text : "Non-Hydrocarbon Component"
            font_size : 20
            size_hint : (0.5,0.09)
            color: 0.3,0.4,0.5,1
            pos_hint : {"center_x":0.75,"top" : 0.8}
            background_color : (14/255,195/255,110/225,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        Label :
            text : "CO2"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint : {"x":0.5, "top":0.712}
            background_color : (5/255,95/255,53/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput : 
            id:co2
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0.75, "top":0.712}

        Label :
            text : "H2S"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint : {"x":0.5, "top":0.672}
            background_color : (6/255,124/255,69/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput : 
            id:h2s
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0.75, "top":0.672}

        Label :
            text : "N2"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos_hint : {"x":0.5, "top":0.632}
            background_color : (8/255,152/255,85/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput : 
            id:n2
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0.75, "top":0.632}

        Label :
            text : "Reservoir and Separator Data"
            font_size : 20
            size_hint : (0.5,0.09)
            color: 0.3,0.4,0.5,1
            pos_hint : {"center_x":0.25,"top" : 0.5}
            background_color : (14/255,195/255,110/225,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        Label :
            text : "Reservoir Temperature"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0, "top":0.41}
            color: 1,1,1,1
            background_color : (5/255,95/255,53/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput : 
            id:tres
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.04)
            pos_hint : {"x":0.25, "top":0.41}

        Label :
            text : "Initial Reservoir pressure"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 200,25
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos : 0,200
            background_color : (6/255,124/255,69/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput : 
            id:pres
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 200,25
            pos : 200,200

        Label :
            text : "Separator Temperature"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 200,25
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos : 0,175
            background_color : (8/255,152/255,85/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput : 
            id:tsep
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 200,25
            pos : 200,175

        Label :
            text : "Separator pressure"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 200,25
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos : 0,150
            background_color : (9/255,181/255,101/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput :
            id:psep
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 200,25
            pos : 200,150

        Label :
            text : "Standard pressure"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 200,25
            color: 1,1,1,1
            pos : 0,125
            background_color : (10/255,209/255,116/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
        TextInput : 
            id:pstd
            multiline:False
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 200,25
            pos : 200,125

        Label :
            text : "Water Formation Data"
            font_size : 20
            size_hint : (0.5,0.09)
            color: 0.3,0.4,0.5,1
            pos_hint : {"center_x":0.75,"top" : 0.5}
            background_color : (71/255,220/255,141/255,1)
            canvas.before:
                Color :
                    rgba : self.background_color
                Rectangle :
                    size : self.size
                    pos : self.pos
            Label :
                size_hint : (None,None)
                size : 400,125
                color: 0.3,0.4,0.5,1
                pos: 400,125
                background_color : (5/255,95/255,53/255,1)
                canvas.before:
                    Color :
                        rgba : self.background_color
                    Rectangle :
                        size : self.size
                        pos : self.pos

            Label :
                text : "Condition"
                font_size : 12
                size_hint : (None,None)
                size : 400,25
                color: 1,1,1,1
                pos : 400,225
                background_color : (6/255,124/255,69/255,1)
                canvas.before:
                    Color :
                        rgba : self.background_color
                    Rectangle :
                        size : self.size
                        pos : self.pos
            ToggleButton :
                id:sat
                text : "Gas-Saturated Brine"
                size_hint : (None,None)
                size : 180, 60
                pos : 420, 155
                group : 'Condition'
     
            ToggleButton :
                id:free
                text : "Gas-Free Brine"
                size_hint : (None,None)
                size : 180, 60
                pos : 610, 155
                group : 'Condition'
                state: "normal" 
                    

            Label :
                text : "Total Dissolved Solid"
                font_size : 12
                size_hint : (None,None)
                size : 200,25
                color: 1,1,1,1
                pos : 400,125
                background_color : (10/255,209/255,116/255,1)
                canvas.before:
                    Color :
                        rgba : self.background_color
                    Rectangle :
                        size : self.size
                        pos : self.pos
            TextInput : 
                id:tds
                multiline:False
                font_size : 12
                size_hint : (None,None)
                size : 200,25
                pos : 600,125
        
        Button :
            id:btn
            text : "CALCULATE"
            size_hint : (None,None)
            size : 180, 60
            pos_hint : {"center_x":0.5,"y":0.05}
            on_press : root.calculate()
            on_release : app.root.current = "second"

<MyLayout2>:

    name : "second"
    ubah:ubah
    GridLayout :
        cols : 1
        Label :
            id:ubah
            text : "test"
        Button :
            text : "Back"
            on_press : root.press()
            on_release : app.root.current = "main"
```

I am trying to print it before pass to another class, so it has values when in it class but empty when changing class, can anyone help me about this coz im new in kivy

Comment: are you sure that there is actually some text in pstd? or any other element? Or is it empty in new class but in MyLayout it is filled? that would be weird... Please add more information to clarify the problem

Comment: yes because I print it before passing to another class, and it has values, but when Im printing it after pass it it will be None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value comes empty because the function can't see the current running class with the values you want. If you want to see the changes you have done and not the initial values you need to make the classes see each other.

First get yout app running, then go to its screen manager. There you can get the screen whith the values you want and then execute the function.

```py
class MyLayout2(Screen):
    def press(self):
        running = App.get_running_app()
        manager = running.root
        layout1 = manager.get_screen('main')
        print(layout1.calculate())
        # Or just print(App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('main').calculate())
```

Comment: sorry but, I still get None when I using this code, any other idea?

Comment: Can you pass the rest of the code so I can test with the changes on `ptsd`

Comment: Can i pass the values using def __init__ (self) ?
I'm trying to pass it but it will say
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'root'

Comment: I didn't understand what you're trying to do

Comment: If you're trying to pass the values in the class init it won't work because your App won't be ready yet